# "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" error with Flask and MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to send a GET request to my Mongo server, and this is the current issue I am having.

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)')>]>
```

I am unable to figure out what is happening. My code looks about correct so I am a bit confused.

Here is my app/main file:

```
from flask import Flask

from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

db = MongoEngine()

# Did pip install certifi for security certifications

def create_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
if config is not None:
    app.config.from_object(config)

db.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

from user.views import user_page
# This means that we will use /user/login....
# To access the login page
app.register_blueprint(user_page, url_prefix="/user")

return app
```

Here is my config file:

```
# MONGODB_DB = 'my-db'
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'host': 'mongodb+srv://jack123:coolPass@my-db.ap6mq.mongodb.net/my-db?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
}
```

I'd certainly appreciate any sort of help on this! This is something I have been stuck on for a while now. I don't know where to get the certificate or how to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt certifi is going to do anything *automatically* for MongoDB connections.

If your system doesn't come with the certificates needed for Atlas, most likely you will need to:

- Figure out/hunt down the CA certificate that Atlas uses (consult Atlas documentation, if this doesn't help you can extract the CA certificate from the connection using `openssl` command-line tool)
- Provide this certificate to pymongo using a URI option (consult pymongo documentation for how to do this)